# Выполнение действия при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: django

Не особо представляю как реализовать какое-либо действие при нажатии кнопки на сайте. Идея такова, чтобы сделать 9 кнопок. При нажатии на одну из них должно возвращаться определённое значение, в моём случае название блюда. Затем оно выводится в список блюд для заказа. Что-то вроде добавления продукта в корзину. Названия всех блюд есть. Сразу перешёл к джанго, не особо разобравшись в питоне, т.к. поджимает время и не могу ничего придумать. Судя по тому, что я нашёл, возможно стоит использовать onclick, но что именно происходит не понимаю.

*foods\models.py*

```
from django.db import models


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку, можно посылать `AJAX` на `Django`-представление, например. Пока что мне не понятно, какой путь решения Вы выбрали и в чём таки требуется помощь.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я не понимаю как мне записать в шаблоне кнопку с обращением к представлению и каким образом я могу из представления сделать вывод в шаблоне.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужна будет модель для "список блюд для заказа" и в ней определить поле (например) foods со связью ForeginKey которая будет связывать заказ с блюдами, ее так же лучше определить для удобства т.к потом может потребоваться отслеживать статус заказа, коментарии к нему и т.д.

Простой вариант это написать в `view.py` функцию которая будет обрабатывать POST  запрос, получать из `request.data` 2 параметра `product_id` и `order_id`. 
И привязать ее к url например: `order/add/`

А самый простой вариант можешь отправлять GET запрос а необходимые `id` получать их  url и связывать их. В таком случае url будет выглядеть как-то так: `/order/<int:pk>/product-add/<int:pk>/` 
 вместо int:pk в запросе с фронтенда надо будет вставить нужные id.

В view.py 
ты получаешь нужны модели по id с помощью [Django ORM](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_orm/), связываешь их и сохраняешь. В ответ возвращаешь `response` с статусом 201, чтобы было понятно что все прошло успешно или с статусом 404 если что то пошло не так.

На фронтенде просто напишешь функцию которая делает POST или GET запрос с нужными данными. И привязываешь ее к onclick в button.

Самый сложный и правильный вариант использовать [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Пишешь сериализаторы для моделей определяешь в urls.py какой то путь по типу '/order/add/' и для него делаешь в view.py функцию которая будет обрабатывать post запрос, добавляя в модель заказа нужное блюдо по id. Отправляешь post запрос на выбранной тобой URL с data {order_id='12', product_id='21'}

Comment: не особо конечно понял, но... Как я понял, мне надо в модели ещё сделать поля с айдишниками заказов и блюд, когда айди блюд будут меняться, айди заказа будет тот же, что позволит добавить нужное кол-во блюд. Кнопка при нажатии посылает эти айди в представление, они сохраняются в полях модели, потом я привязываю view к url и пишу там **/order/<int:pk>/product-add/<int:pk>/**, далее представление как-то сообщает шаблону, что необходимо вывести в заказ с таким-то айди блюдо с таким-то айди. Да, понял я, конечно, плохо, видимо не справлюсь я с этим